# How to obtain parametric models using Z3?

Tags: z3

Given this formula,

```
(p & (x < 0)) | (~p & (x > 0)).
```

How could I get these 2 "parametric" models in Z3:

```
{p=true, x<0}
{p=false, x>0}
```

When I submit this SMTLIB program to Z3,

```
(declare-const p Bool)
(declare-const x  Int)
(assert (or (and p (< x 0)) (and (not p) (> x 0))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(assert (or (not p) (not (= x -1))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

it gives me concrete models instead (e.g. {p=true, x=-1}, {p=true, x=-2}, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

SMT solvers do not produce non-concrete models; it's just not how they work.  What you want is essentially some form of "simplification" in steroids, and while you can use an SMT solver to help you in simplifying expressions, you'll have to build a tool on top that understands the kind of simplifications you'd like to see. Bottom line: What you'd consider "simple" as a person, and what an automated SMT-solver sees as "simple" are usually quite different from each other; and given lack of normal forms over arbitrary theories, you cannot expect them to do a good job.

If these sorts of simplifications is what you're after, you might want to look at symbolic math packages, such as sympy, Mathematica, etc.